# Newb Geth Command Line question about sending transactions to other nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, cli

I have installed geth on linux, created a wallet, and was running my own node.

After upgrading, I am way behind, only on block 3700000 ish.

Is there a way I can send ethereum from my geth cli wallet using a public node of sorts?

I guess I could import my private keys to some other wallet and use their node, but was looking for a better solution.

Comment: so in the past when my node was up to date I used "geth attach".  My question is what command line argument do I need to use to send transactions via a public node?  i.e. geth --connect to someother node other than localhost